# I cant seem to position images how i want in my webdesign

Tags: html, css

I would like to position the second image (IMG_5347_small.jpg) in the .mainHeader img so that it is always displayed on the right side of the screen aligned with the content.
How do i do that?
I have searched google for this but found nothing useful.
Hope you can help

```css
body {
    background-image: url('img/tape-measure.jpg');
    color: #000305;
    font-size: 87.5%;
    font-family: 'Coming Soon', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', cursive;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: left;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    
}

a:link, a:visited {
    color: #CF5C3F;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #CF5C3F;
    color: #fff;
}

.body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
    clear: both;
}

.mainHeader img {
    max-width: 30%;
 height: auto;
}

.mainHeader img .Margrit {
 max-width: 30%;
 height: auto;
}

.mainHeader nav {
    background-color: #9cb34f;
 height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainHeader nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    height: 20px;
}

.mainHeader nav a:hover, .mainHeader nav a:active,
.mainHeader nav .active a:link, mainHeader nav .active a:visited {
    background-color: #CF5C3F;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li a {
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainContent {
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}

.topcontent {
    background-color: #9cb34f;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 3% 5%;
    margin-top: 2%;
}

.bottomcontent {
    background-color: #9cb34f;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 3% 5%;
    margin-top: 2%;
}

.post-info {
    font-style: italic;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 90%;
}

.top-sidebar {
    width: 21%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #9cb34f;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 2% 0 2% 3%;
    padding: 2% 3%;
}

.middle-sidebar {
    width: 21%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #9cb34f;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    padding: 2% 3%;

}

.bottom-sidebar {
    width: 21%;
    float: right;
    background-color: #9cb34f;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    padding: 2% 3%;
}

.top-sidebar h2, .middle-sidebar h2, .bottom-sidebar h2 {
 color: #CF5C3F;
}

.mainFooter {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #9cb34f;
    margin: 2% 0;
}

.mainFooter p {
    width: 92%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    color: #fff;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 600px)
{
    .body {
        width: 90%;
        font-size: 95%;
    }
    
    .mainHeader img {
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    
    .mainHeader nav {
        height: 160px;
    }

    .mainHeader nav ul {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    .mainHeader nav ul li {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        
    }

    .mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
        padding: 10px 25px;
        height: 20px;
        display: block;
    }

    .content {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 2%;
    }
    
    .post-info {
        display: none;
    }

    .topcontent {
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 3% 5%;
        margin-top: 2%;
        margin-bottom: 4%;
    }

    .bottomcontent {
        margin-top: 3%;
    }
    
    
    .top-sidebar, . middle-sidebar, .bottom-sidebar {
        width: 94%;
        margin: 2% 0 2% 0;
        padding: 2% 3%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
  <title>Couture Anni</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coming+Soon" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body class="body">
  <header class="mainHeader">
   <img src="resources/img/Content_variation_800_e.png" alt="Logo">
   <img class="Margrit" src="resources/img/IMG_5347_small.jpg" alt="Annamaria Hofstetter">
   
   <nav>
    
    <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
    
      </nav>
  </header>
  
  <div class="maincontent">
   <div class="content">
    <article class="topcontent">
     <header>
      <h2><a href="#" title="First post">First post</a></h2>
     </header>
                    
                    <footer>
                        <p class="post-info">Diese Seite ist unter Bearbeitung.</p>
                    </footer>
                    
                    <content>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
                    </content>
                
                </article>
                
                <article class="bottomcontent">
     <header>
      <h2><a href="#" title="Second post">Second post</a></h2>
     </header>
                    
                    <footer>
                        <p class="post-info">Diese Seite ist unter Bearbeitung.</p>
                    </footer>
                    
                    <content>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
                    </content>
                
                </article>
                
            </div>
  </div>
        
        <aside class="top-sidebar">
            <article>
                <h2>Top sidebar</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
            </article>
        </aside>
        
        <aside class="middle-sidebar">
            <article>
                <h2>Middle sidebar</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
            </article>
        </aside>
        
        <aside class="bottom-sidebar">
            <article>
                <h2>Bottom sidebar</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
            </article>
        </aside>
        
        <footer class="mainFooter">
            <p>Copyright &copy; <a href="#" title="couture-anni">couture-anni.ch</a></p>
        </footer>
        
    </body>


</html>
```

[image: Images are right next to each other but they shouldnt be]

Comment: Not sure why you wasn't able to post it without the "lorem ipsum" part, but I edited it out - Hope it's fine with you

Comment: Because it said it was mostly code and i couldnt post unless i gave a little bit more description so i did.

Comment: Oh, OK. So first thing - You have this selector `.mainHeader img .Margrit` but you have space between `img` and `.Margrit` - It should be  `.mainHeader img.Margrit { <your style for that image> }`

Comment: ok i corrected that but how do i place it how i want?

Comment: What happens when you add `.mainHeader { position: relative; } .mainHeader img.Margrit { position: absolute; right: 0; } .mainHeader nav {margin-top: <actual-size-of-image-in-px>}`?

Comment: ok i did the following:

Comment: .mainHeader {
 position: relative;
}

.mainHeader img.Logo {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 50px;
 max-width: 30%;
 height: auto;
}

.mainHeader img.Margrit {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 max-width: 30%;
 height: auto;
}
.mainHeader nav {
    background-color: #9cb34f;
 height: 40px;
 margin-top: 300px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

Comment: Now the problem is this: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByvBm4p4Y2J3Z1FjaHo1a2pOclE

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your CSS file!

.mainHeader img .Margrit {
    max-width: 30%;
    height: auto;``